# On tag:scrabble, tag:word-games, tag:games

Tags: discussion, tags

I just rolled back someone's edit to add [scrabble](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble). I *really* don't think we need tags for things like Scrabble, Boggle, etc. Perhaps we can just use the more generic [word-games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-games)? Also, is there a meaningful difference between [games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) and [word-games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-games)?

Comment: Is EL&U the right place for any of those? Was the tag added for [Scrabble help sites](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34418/scrabble-help-sites-migrated)? If so, that question has already been moved to Board and Card Games.SE.  Maybe the purpose of the tag would be to alert us that the question probably should be migrated.

Comment: @jim: It was added to a second question but I rolled it back.

Comment: @MrHen: All my fault.  I wasn't too sure of myself, though.  Thanks for stepping in!

Comment: @drm65: I don't think you did anything wrong but I do feel that we should be a little careful about mentioning specific games like that. No harm; no foul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't need those tags because EL&U is not a site about board games.
Tags help to categorize the questions, but the categorization level must not be too detailed. Thus, tags such as [fruit-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruit-nouns), [pet-names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-names), [tree-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree-nouns) are not necessary because EL&U is not supposed to answer in detail to questions about, e.g, fruit nouns; there is already [nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) and that is enough for the purposes of the site.

In the specific, questions about table, board, and word games are not supposed to be asked on EL&U; therefore, [scrabble](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble), [games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games), and [word-games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-games) are not necessary on EL&U.

As a side note, I would add that such tags would make users misunderstand the purpose of the site, and I feel them more dangerous than the questions about jokes.

Comment: I'm accepting this until someone strongly disagrees.

Comment: the other thing to consider with tags is "who would want to *subscribe* to such a tag?" If the answer is 'nobody', then that tag probably should not exist...